# Resistance of depletion region of PN Junction

Tags: semiconductor-physics

[image: Diode Model]

It seems that in picture D, the Depletion region is gone because quantitatively we have V= Vj+RI where Vj is the opposite of the built in potential of the depletion region but R is the resistance of which region then?

If it is the Depletion region's resistance how come the depletion region is still there when the voltage V is more than Vj?

Thank you

Comment: Please, can somebody reply

Comment: What is there really to reply to? The description in the text is accurate - these are large signal approximations to diode behavior - the are made so that you explicitly ignore actual device physics and replace it with a simplified lumped model.